# efficient estimator and CRLB (Cramer Rao Lower Bound)

Tags: self-learning, statistical-inference, estimation

I have recently been studying some classical inference and I have come across this question about an efficient estimator and CRLB in a mathematical statistics textbook.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda^{3}x^{2}}{2}e^{-\lambda x} & x>0\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}$$

Two things I want to calculate is

a) efficient estimator of $\lambda^{-1}$

b) Cramer-Rao Lower Bound (CRLB) for $\lambda^{-1}$

The pdf above isn't named but it looks similar to a gamma pdf in some ways.

So far I have worked out the log likelihood to be, $log(f|\lambda)=3log\lambda+2logx-\lambda x-log2$

also
$\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}=\frac{3}{\lambda}-x$. Now i'm confused to exactly what the efficient estimator is here.

For CRLB, I have calculated $$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\lambda^{2}}=-\frac{3}{\lambda^{2}}$$
$$-\mathbb{E}[-\frac{3}{\lambda^{2}}]=\frac{3}{\lambda^{2}}$$ There is no x, hence I can't take expectation of anything, is this correct?

One of things putting me off in this question is also the $\lambda^{-1}$ mentioned in the question, most of the time, I've done questions where is refers to parameter itself, not the inverse of it.

Comment: Ok where are you stuck . . . Show your work . . . yes it's gamma . . .

Comment: Hi, I've just added some of my working, The $\lambda^{-1}$ is putting me off at present, also the efficient estimator, I don't know how to interpret the first partial derivate to establish the efficient estimator although I do believe you need the first derivative to calculate it.